# Handling exception in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, exception, nsmutabledictionary

**First look at the following Objective-c code:**

```
NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *oldDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: oldDictPath];
@try {
        [newDict setObject:[oldDict objectForKey:@"count"] forKey:@"newCount"];
}
//I want to take "count" value from oldDict and set this to NewDict
@catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"%@ ",exception.name);
        NSLog(@"Reason: %@ ",exception.reason);
}
@finally {
        NSLog(@"@@finaly Always Executes");
}
```

I want to take "count" value from oldDict and set this to NewDict.And the problem is `[oldDict objectForKey:@"count"]` may ***nil*** sometime.This can be handle by `if` condition like

```
if([oldDict objectForKey:@"count"] != nil){ //then add to newDict}
```

OldDict may have 1000 pair, so i don't want to put 1000 `if statements`.

***@try and @catch in above code not handling this exception. Can any body tell me the best way to handle this exceptions.***
My code is getting crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this, no need to add a try catch just call `zeroIfNil` or make necessary function like `emptyIfNull` etc.

```
-(void)someFunc
{
    NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *oldDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: oldDictPath];

   [newDict setObject:[self zeroIfNil:[oldDict objectForKey:@"count"]] forKey:@"newCount"];
   // TODO : Access all values of of oldDict here and parse them with the 
   // help of custom functions as i suggested.
} 

-(NSString *)zeroIfNil:(id)object
{
    if(object == nil) {
        return @"0";
    }
    else {
        return object;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *keys = @{ @"count": @"newCount", @"asdf": @"newAsdf" };

for (id key in keys) {
    id object = [oldDict objectForKey:key];
    if (object) [newDict setObject:object forKey:[keys objectForKey:key]];
}
```

Edit: This snippet defines `keys` dictionary that maps old keys to new keys and iterates over it, assigning oldDict[oldKey] to newDict[newKey] for keys that exist in oldDict. This avoids manual coding of thousands of assignments, as well as exception handling observed in the question.